# Return an Array of Constant Field values a certain Type from a Static Class

Tags: c#, .net

Given this code:

```
public static class SubClass
{
    public const long poperty1 = 365635;
    public const long poperty2 = 156346;
    public const long poperty3 = 280847;
    .
    .
    public const long propertyN = 29145;

}
```

A class with N long properties. Is possible to add a method to return an IEnumerable with all the properties values?

Comment: Yes. With Reflection.

Comment: Those are fields, not poperties

Comment: Your example code is indicative of you doing something wrong.  Use a collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to demonstrate how you could do this very simply with an [iterator method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators)...

```
public static IEnumerable<long> GetConstantsAsEnumerable()
{
    yield return poperty1;
    yield return poperty2;
    yield return poperty3;
}
```

...or an [array initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays#array-initialization)...

```
public static long[] GetConstantsAsArray()
{
    return new long[] {
        poperty1,
        poperty2,
        poperty3
    };
}
```

Of course, depending on how big `N` is either method could grow very long.  Unlike [@TheGeneral's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52193384/150605), as constants are added or deleted you would also have to manually update the methods to reflect the change.

Also, to [@maccettura's point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52193208/return-an-array-of-constant-field-values-a-certain-type-from-a-static-class#comment91336294_52193208), if these numbered constants are related and you want to access them in a collection-like manner, it would be better to store them as a collection in the first place.  You could use an array...

```
public static class SubClass
{
    public static readonly long[] properties = new long[] { 365635, 156346, 280847 };
}
```

...or, to ensure the elements are never modified, a [`ReadOnlyCollection<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1)...

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public static class SubClass
{
    public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<long> properties = 
        new ReadOnlyCollection<long>(
            new long[] { 365635, 156346, 280847 }
        );
}
```

If the values are unique and ordering is not important a [`HashSet<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1) might be appropriate...

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class SubClass
{
    public static readonly HashSet<long> properties = new HashSet<long>(
        new long[] { 365635, 156346, 280847 }
    );
}
```

...and if you're using .NET Core and, again, want to ensure the set is never modified you can use an [`ImmutableHashSet<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablehashset-1)...

```
using System.Collections.Immutable;

public static class SubClass
{
    public static readonly ImmutableHashSet<long> properties = ImmutableHashSet.Create<long>(
        new long[] { 365635, 156346, 280847 }
    );
}
```

All of the above types can be enumerated as-is with no need for a wrapper method.

Answer (score 3):

> Is possible to add a method to return an **IEnumerable** with all the
>   properties values?

You can use this, It will select all public constant long fields from the static class

```
var result = typeof(SubClass).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                             .Where(x=> x.IsLiteral && !x.IsInitOnly && x.FieldType == typeof(long))
                             .Select(x => x.GetRawConstantValue());
```

---

**You can read it as follows**

[typeof (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/typeof)

> Used to obtain the System.Type object for a type. A typeof expression
>   takes the following form:

[Type.GetFields Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getfields?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Type_GetFields)

> Gets the fields of the current Type.

[BindingFlags Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> **Public**  Specifies that public members are to be included in the
>   search.
>
> **Static**  Specifies that static members are to be included in the
>   search.

**Which returns**

[FieldInfo Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Discovers the attributes of a field and provides access to field
>   metadata.

**Filter by (Where)**

[FieldInfo.IsLiteral Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.isliteral?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Gets a value indicating whether the value is written at compile time
>   and cannot be changed.

[FieldInfo.IsInitOnly Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.isinitonly?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Reflection_FieldInfo_IsInitOnly)

> Gets a value indicating whether the field can only be set in the body
>   of the constructor.

**Then select with**

[FieldInfo.GetRawConstantValue Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getrawconstantvalue?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Reflection_FieldInfo_GetRawConstantValue)

> Returns a literal value associated with the field by a compiler.